# JqGrid search manipulate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid, automation

I'm working on the client side and my company got a `pbx web maintenance console`. I would like to program this web interface, but there is a `jqgrid`: and the Searchtoolbar not responding for Copy and Paste

The Code :

```
<th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" role="columnheader">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-right: 0.3em; position: relative;">
    <input name="extinf3_name" id="gs_extinf3_name" style="padding: 0px; width: 95%;" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</th>
```

but this is Important:

```
<input name="extinf3_name" id="gs_extinf3_name" style="padding: 0px; width: 95%;" type="text" value="">
```

What I have tried:

```
$("#gs_extinf_name").val("Something") //Not working, coz there is no event

Jquery plugins: Jquery.autotype, typed.js 

keydown, keyup, trigger (keycode) methodes

Simulating Enter
```

Probably the search on enter is turned off and I can't make an automated search.

My Code:

```
function exportieren14() {
try {
    TkAnlage.msie = new ActiveXObject('InternetExplorer.Application')
    TkAnlage.msie.Visible = true
    TkAnlage.msie.Navigate(TkAnlage.url)
    TkAnlage.stack.push(exportieren15)
    window.setTimeout(waitReady,5000)
} catch(e) {
    pyramide.error(e)
}
}

function exportieren15() {
try {
    var body = $(TkAnlage.msie.Document.body) 
    TkAnlage.msie.Document.parentWindow.focus()
    TkAnlage.msie.Document.focus()


 /*     
    var e = TkAnlage.msie.Document.parentWindow.jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 79; 
    e.keyCode = 79;
    body.find("#gs_extinf3_name").trigger(e);

    var e = TkAnlage.msie.Document.parentWindow.jQuery.Event("keyup");
    e.which = 79; 
    e.keyCode = 79;
    body.find("#gs_extinf3_name").trigger(e);

    return;
*/       var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")
    for (var i=0; i<shell.Windows().Count; i++) {
        try {
            var Item = shell.Windows().Item(i);
            if (Item.Document.title=='Web-Programmiersoftware') {
                TkAnlage.msie =  Item
                break;
            }
        }  catch (e) {}
    }

    body.find("#gs_extinf3_name").val('lol')
    body.find("#gs_extinf3_name").submit()




}
catch(e) {
    pyramide.error(e)
}

}
```

What happens:

input value = lol

no search, beacause the grid update when someone types in the seach toolbar instead of having to press enter

Comment: Not very clear as to what you're after!

Comment: Hello ! Sorry but your question is completely incomprehensible. I have no idea what you are looking for. Pbx ? Searchtoolbar ? What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: You should post **JavaScript code** which you use. I suppose that you need to add `searchOnEnter: false` option of `filterToolbar`, but I can only guess what you do, what you want to implement and what is your current problem. Sorry...

Comment: Okey, so. There is a ns1000 panasonic web maintenance console. With this I can make settings on phones in the company and this web interface based on javascript and using jsgrid too. I want to modify some input fields for example the input field of the jqgrid filterToolbar. To make automated search. But when i say "Navigate to the Url ( 10.x.x.x) and Login, Click there and there, I cant make an automated search in this jsgrid table because the searchOnEnter : false"